# How to get all the children and sub-children of XML file using Scala

Tags: xml, scala

Here is the example XML files:

```
<Parent name="test">
  <Field name="one" />
  <Child name="child1">
    <Sub-Child name="subchild1"/>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

Here is my codes:

```
val data = XML.load(new FileInputStream(new File("test.xml")))

val execSeq = (data\\"Parent").filter(
        node=>node.attribute("name").exists(
                name => name.text=="test"
        )
    )\"_"
```

But it could only get name attributes from **Field** and **Child**, not **Sub-Child**

I want the result should be:
one,child1,subchild1

How to get attribute from **Sub-Child** as well in Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use double back slashes: 
`\\"_"` instead of `\"_"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `_` wildcard:

```
data \\ "_"
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/xml/NodeSeq.scala#L127